# How to setup Google Analytics goal for 2 pages without duplicate results?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have 2 pages for contact in a website. Without getting into details, there's a reason for this and these are not duplicate pages.

I would like to combine the results from both without duplicates, meaning, if somebody goes to both pages, it only counts as 1 goal, so does if they visit either one.

Is this possible in Google Analytics for goals?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is easy to do in Analytics using event goals. So what you would do is to configure both confirmation pages to fire an event upon successful submission. Then in Analytics you create a goal which is based upon that event. This way the one goal will count both contact forms.

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide for info on setting up an event.

Comment: Isn't event assuming you do something on a page? There's nothing to do on this pages besides seeing a phone number for example.

Comment: Hi, events can be used for anything; they can be triggered on page load as well as attaching them to events which a user might do on a page.

Comment: Do you know how to trigger an event on page load with the new universal analytics code?

Answer (score 0):

You should set Goal as "contact.php|contact2.php"

First url is url of first contact page, and second one is url of another contact page.

Basicly it means that Goal is view of contact.php OR contact2.php

Comment: The whole point of the question is to avoid the same person completing both goals, in other words, I would have a fake number of completed goals. Instead of one person looking at either page, I would have 2 as result for only one person.

Comment: Either going to contact.php or contact2.php or seeing them both will appear as one goal completed in Google Analytics.

Comment: Except, to me both goals are the same. If one person completes both goals, the results are duplicate to me, not on analytics.